# Unable to attach a running process with 'ltrace' command on Linux server

Tags: ltrace

I want to attach a process with ltrace command to trace one specific library calls. But when i used the below basic options, ltrace command throws error as below

```
bash-3.2$ **ltrace -l /path/libxml2.so.2.6.32 -p 26120**
```

**failed to init breakpoints 26120

Cannot attach to pid 26120: Success**

When I tried the same option with an executable ltrace is tracing the calls to that specific library (libxml2.so.2.6.32).

My server information:

```
2.6.18-348.6.1.el5 #1 SMP Fri Apr 26 09:21:26 EDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

ltrace vertion:

bash-3.2$ ltrace -V
*ltrace version 0.5.
Copyright (C) 1997-2006 Juan Cespedes .
This is free software; see the GNU General Public Licence
version 2 or later for copying conditions.  There is NO warranty.*

I googled this error message but didn't get any useful information. From the error message I understood , the ltrace program is unable to set the breakpoint on libxml2 library. But I really don't understand why it is failing when ltrace is able to trace a sample program.

Has anyone faced this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks,
Sakthivel

Answer (score 0):

That's an ancient version of `ltrace`, with many known bugs.  Please use latest version (0.7.3) from http://www.ltrace.org